# Not able to submit image with POST method using jmeter

Tags: performance, api, post, file-upload, jmeter

**My Http Request**

[image: My Http Request]

**My Header Manger**
[image: My Header Manager]

I am getting error code as 400 - BAD REQUEST

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2021-03-20 06:20:18 GMT 
Load time:551
Connect Time:40
Latency:551
Size in bytes:336
Sent bytes:652
Headers size in bytes:144
Body size in bytes:192
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:400
Response message:BAD REQUEST


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Comment: Are you able to submit request through postman? There are different ways to upload image data. As a file as attachment or as base64 string. How does the system work for you?

Comment: Hi I am able to submit the request from Postman, I tried by changing parameters and it works then thank you

Comment: You have selected multi-part form data option. Hope this option supported by your server as well. Also, is it possible to provide screenshot from `View Results Tree` - Request view?

Answer (score 0):

As per [400 Bad Request description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

> The client should not repeat this request without modification.

so it means that the request you're sending is malformed somehow, i.e. incorrect path or missing header or invalid/incorrect/missing parameter(s)

If you can execute the request manually using browser you should be able to record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just **make sure to copy the file you're uploading into the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**, this way JMeter will be able to properly generate the HTTP Request sampler and HTTP Header Manager.

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.